# CreateFile with East Asian Path Names Fails with Invalid Volume Path or FileName

Tags: windows

1. I have a legacy application running on Windows with locale set to Korea (Hangul)
2. I created a GDIPLUS C++ wrapper for image compression (png, jpg,etc) to use in the legacy App.
3. The application has 2 processes A and B. Process B is a child of A.
4. Process B generates a bitmap and compresses it via the wrapper: Bitmap->Save(Hangul-file-name.png).
5. Process A attempts to open Hangul-file-name.png and fails with error code 123 (volume, path or filename invalid).
6. What is the WIN API used by Bitmap->Save() that enables it to successfully create Hangul-file-name.png?  I would think
   that the Bitmap->Save() must eventually call CreateFile()??
7. Are there any flags I can add to the CreateFile() that would resolve this problem?

---

```
// Called from legacy application. 
//  pszFileName - contains a DBCS ANSI Hangul path name "자동연결기능수행_(perform_autolink_functions)_ffbd"  volume info left out.
BOOL SavePng(char * pszFileName, HBITMAP bmhandle, HPALETTE palette, int quality)
{
    if(pszFileName == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    // Convert the smalltalk DBCS  ANSI string to unicode.
    int slength = strlen(pszFileName);
    wchar_t *uFilename = new wchar_t[slength + 1];
    uFilename[slength] = L'\0';
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pszFileName, -1, uFilename, slength);

    BOOL result = SaveImage(uFilename, L"image/png", bmhandle, palette, quality);
    delete uFilename;
    return result;
}

// Create a compressed image file
BOOL SaveImage(LPCWSTR pszFileName, LPCWSTR encoding, HBITMAP bmhandle, HPALETTE palette, int quality)
{
    CLSID encoderClsid;
    if( GetEncoderClsid(encoding, &encoderClsid) > 0)
    {
        EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
        encoderParameters.Count = 1;
        encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderQuality;
        encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
        encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;
        encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &quality;
        Bitmap* bm = new Bitmap(bmhandle, palette);
        bm->Save(pszFileName,&encoderClsid, &encoderParameters);
        delete bm;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Attempt to open file for reading
//  pszFileName: "C:\CORE2net80\users\Administrator\자동연결기능수행_(perform_autolink_functions).png" (sample)
HANDLE OpenReadOnly(char * pszFileName)
{
    // Convert the smalltalk DBCS ansi string to unicode.
    int slength = strlen(pszFileName);

    int lenw = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pszFileName, slength, 0, 0);
    if(lenw > 0)
    {
        wchar_t *uFilename = new wchar_t[lenw + 1];
        uFilename[lenw] = L'\0';

        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pszFileName, slength, uFilename, lenw);

        HANDLE h = CreateFile(uFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if( h ==  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            DWORD en = GetLastError(); // Error 123 (volume, path or filename invalid)
            return 0;
        }
        return h;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is likely that the two programs are using different file names.  Process Monitor will tell you what the difference is, which may help you identify the cause.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any magic.  `Bitmap->Save()` will eventually call `CreateFileW` (the Unicode version of `CreateFile`).

You have code for converting the MBCS filename into Unicode in both `SavePng` and `OpenReadOnly`, and it doesn't work the same.  Create a single function to do the filename conversion and you should get consistent results.